# Terminology for sequence that is $\Theta\left(\frac1n\right)$

Tags: terminology, asymptotics

For a sequence $\{\epsilon_n\}$ that approaches $0$ as $n\to\infty$, we say that it approaches zero "geometrically" if 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\epsilon_n}{\epsilon_{n-1}} = \lambda$$ for some $\lambda$ with $|\lambda < 1|$.  Thus for example the sequence $2^{-n}$ approaches zero geometrically.  For a sequence that approaches zero geometrically, the number of zeros in the decimal expansion of $\epsilon_n$ grows linearly with $n$.

I have also heard the term "approaches zero exponentially (fast)" applied to sequences where 
 $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\epsilon_n}{\epsilon_{n-1}^\alpha} = \rho$$
for some $\alpha > 1$ and some finite non-zero $\rho$.  Thus for example, if $s_n$ is the value obtained by the $n$-th iteration of Newton's algorithm in calculating $\sqrt{2}$ starting with any iniital guess $s_0 \in \Bbb{N}$, and $\epsilon_n = \sqrt{2}-s_n$, then the sequence $\{\epsilon_n\}$  approaches zero exponentially fast (as the error in Newton for the square root falls like
$$
\epsilon_{n+1} = \frac{\epsilon_n^2}{2(\sqrt{2}+\epsilon_n)}\implies  
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\epsilon_n}{\epsilon_{n-1}^2} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}
$$
For sequence that approaches zero exponentially, the number of zeros in the decimal expansion of $\epsilon_n$ grows geometrically with $n$.

My question is, what do we call a sequence that approaches zero 
"like $\frac1n$", that is, where 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} n\epsilon_n = \gamma
$$ 
Or to be more general, when for some positive power $p$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} n^p \epsilon_n = \gamma
$$ 
For $p=1$ I might call this approaching zero "harmonically" but I'm not sure if that is accepted terminology.

Comment: $\epsilon_n \sim \frac{\gamma}{n}$ or $\epsilon_n = \mathcal{O}( \frac{1}{n})$ is quite clear, why would you want a terminology

Comment: I've heard sequences with $a_n \sim \gamma n^{-p}$ called growing / going to zero "polynomially" and "following a power law [at the tail]". But I personally would say "goes to zero like $1/n$" or "goes to zero like $1/n^2$" etc.